# Worker design pattern

Tags: oop, design-patterns, worker

What is "worker" design pattern?

Comment: Do you mean the master/worker pattern?

Comment: When I think of "worker" I can't help think about "jobs" -- workers do jobs. Workers handle the queueing/dispatching of jobs, and jobs are discrete units of work, potentially with some state like "repeatable", etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It could be that you are after a [worker thread pattern](http://web.archive.org/web/20100724223152/www.eecho.info/Echo/design-pattern/worker-thread-pattern-java/), where you use a queue to schedule tasks that you want to be processed "offline" by a worker thread.
Some solutions will use a [pool of worker threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern) instead of single thread to achieve performance gains by utilising paralelisation.

Answer (score 1):

Something like [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) comes to mind. Where multiple tasks can be performed in parallel on worker nodes.

Edit: As @larsmans mentioned, this is known as the [Master/Worker](http://blog.gigaspaces.com/2009/08/24/the-master-worker-pattern/) pattern.

Comment: Dead link try https://docs.gigaspaces.com/sbp/master-worker-pattern.html

Comment: Obsolete link, use https://docs.gigaspaces.com/solution-hub/master-worker-pattern.html