# Symfony run command from controller on the server

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-console

I want to clear the cache from the controller. I have defined the command as a service and call it.

```
clear_cache_command_service:
    class: Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\CacheClearCommand
    calls:
       - [setContainer, ["@service_container"] ]
```

In my controller I have a form to choose a command, and when the cache-clearing command is chosen it runs:

```
    $clearCacheCommand = $this->container->get('clear_cache_command_service');
    $clearCacheCommand->run(new ArrayInput(array()), new ConsoleOutput());
```

This however runs for a while, since it also warms up the cache (I actually want it to also warm it up). It also times out so I need to `set_time_limit` it, too.

Is there a way to return a response in the browser and let the command run and finish on the server? I don't want the client to keep waiting for it to finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it. This will immediately return a response and have the command run in background. Not sure how much of a bad practice it is.

```
/**
 * @Service("background_command_runner")
 */
class BackgroundCommandRunner
{
    private $kernelDir;


    /**
     * @InjectParams({
     *     "kernelDir" = @Inject("%kernel.root_dir%")
     * })
     */
    public function __construct($kernelDir)
    {
        $this->kernelDir = $kernelDir;
    }

    public function run($cmd)
    {
        $path = $this->kernelDir . '\console ';

        $fullCmd = "php " . $path . $cmd;

        if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows") {
            pclose(popen("start /B " . $fullCmd, "r"));
        } else {
            exec($fullCmd . " >> logs/theme.log &");
        }
    }

    public function clearCache($env = "dev", $warm = true)
    {

        $toWarm = $warm ? "" : " --no-warmup";

        $cmd = "cache:clear " . "--env=" . $env . $toWarm;

        $this->run($cmd);

    }


}
```

Comment: it is a bit hackish. It probably will work (I'm not sure about "\" directory separator in linux) but it's not clean code - let's imagine that name of command will change to `cache:clear-now` or `console` will change to `ezpublish` (in fact it is called this way in `ezpublish` cms) and it won't work anymore

Comment: Then those can be added as parameters above. Even so, it's most likely they won't change (while we should not depend on this fact, there are quite a number of projects that have the command hard-coded somewhere in deployment scripts) and it's supposed to be working only for Symfony.

Comment: I've changed it so more commands can be added to it. So far it's working splendidly.

Answer (score 4):

Because of how `php` works - synchronously - it is not possible to do in a "classic" way in which you need to wait until command completes to terminate and send the response. Solution here is to incorporate `worker` pattern. You can find some useful info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945509/worker-design-pattern). Basically you need to add "clear cache" task to queue and let other process handle this queue so in you case call `clear cache` command.

A common solution used in symfony in such cases is using [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/), there's a lot of resources about it:

[Using in symfony](http://cases.azoft.com/using-rabbitmq-in-symfony2-projects/)

[RabbitMQBundle](https://github.com/php-amqplib/RabbitMqBundle)

[Let RabbitMQ Do The Work In Your Symfony2 Application](http://techportal.inviqa.com/2013/11/18/let-rabbitmq-do-the-work-in-your-symfony2-application/)

Answer (score 2):

For running command after response you have to use listener on **kernel.terminate** event. The purpose of this event is to perform tasks after the response was already served to the client.

```
// send the headers and echo the content
$response->send();

// triggers the kernel.terminate event
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

[Listener example](https://github.com/symfony/swiftmailer-bundle/blob/master/EventListener/EmailSenderListener.php)

[The kernel.terminate Event documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html#component-http-kernel-event-table)

Comment: The problem with kernel.terminate is that it will listen at every request and it doesn't make sense when I need it only in one place.

Comment: Another problem is adding too many events for request, response, terminate makes the application slow, I believe. I could be wrong, but it still doesn't make sense to ask for this at every request.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative of RabbitMQ that was mentioned about already, you can take a look to JMSJobBundle
http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSJobQueueBundle/master/installation

Some code example I gave at this my older answer to similar question: [Asynchronously calling a Command in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29601140/asynchronously-calling-a-command-in-symfony2)